# How to select multiple row in a Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing Automation and I am stuck here
[image]

I have to select the last two row as shown in the above figure above. Manually I did it by selecting the row and control button from keyboard. How can I do this from selenium?

I tried using

```
Actions builder = new Actions(StaticDriver.driver);
            builder.Click(LatRow).KeyDown(Keys.Control).Click(secondLatRow).KeyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform();
```

`LastRow` and `secondLastRow` are the webelement to select

It didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it with the following chained actions sequence:

- Click on cell with value "7" in column with name "#"
- Press-and-hold-key SHIFT
- Click on cell with value "8" in column with name "#"
- Release-key SHIFT
- Perform